# using xming to save a file from a lnux computer to a windows computer

Tags: scp, xming

I have seen similar questions on here but I have not been able to find an answer that works for me.

I am using `Xming` to interact with a Linux computer, and I want to save a PDF stored on that computer to my windows computer. How do I do this?

Do I use `scp`? If so, what do I use as the host computer, my windows or the Linux? If anyone could provide an example that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

When you use Xming on windows (or any other X11 server), you only export display/keyboard/mouse from your windows computer to your  Linux machine. Any app you run will use other resources from Linux machine (such as disk, network, sound etc).

So any file you save will be somewhere in your homedir on Linux machine.
If you want in on windows machine, you need to transfer it there. Some windows SCP or SFTP client (like http://filezilla.sf.net) is good option. You would tell it to connect to your Linux host.